# How to workaround pickle's restrictions without global variables?

Tags: python, multithreading, pickle

I currently have this piece of code

```
def predict(features):
    probabilities = _classifier.predict_proba(features * _weights).ravel()
    label = np.argmax(probabilities)
    margin = 2 * probabilities[label] - np.sum(probabilities)
    return label, margin

def run_estimator(weights, X_train=X_train, y_train=y_train, X_test=X_test, y_test=y_test, optimization=True):
    classifier = get_classifier(weights, X_train=X_train, y_train=y_train)

    global _classifier
    global _weights 
    _classifier = classifier
    _weights = weights

    with Pool(processes=8) as pool:
        labels, margins = zip(*pool.imap(predict, X_test))
```

I want to pass the `classifier` and `weights` instances to `predict` method directly, without global variables and creating one big iterable to pass to `imap`. How can I achieve that in the cleanest way?

Note: creating a function inside the `run_estimator` method will not work since the callable passed to `imap` should pickable, and only functions declared at the root level are.

Comment: Hello. Have you possibility to define the function ``predict`` inside the function ``run_estimator`` ? Doing so, ``predict`` in ``(*pool.imap(predict, X_test)`` will look for the instances named ``_classifier`` and ``_weights`` in the local namespace of the function ``run_estimator``

Comment: No. `imap` is implemented using a `Queue`, so any callable passed to it should be picklable. Only functions declared on the main level are picklable.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe like that, defining a partial function `predictor` for each couple of instances `_classifier` and `_weights`:

```
def predict(features,_classifier,_weights):
    probabilities = _classifier.predict_proba(features * _weights).ravel()
    label = np.argmax(probabilities)
    margin = 2 * probabilities[label] - np.sum(probabilities)
    return label, margin

from functools import partial

def run_estimator(weights,
                  X_train=X_train,
                  y_train=y_train,
                  X_test=X_test,
                  y_test=y_test,
                  optimization=True,
                  partial = partial
                  predict = predict):
    
    classifier = get_classifier(weights, 
                                X_train=X_train,
                                y_train=y_train)

    predictor = partial(predict,
                        _classifier = classifier,
                        _weights = weights)

    with Pool(processes=8) as pool:
        labels, margins = zip(*pool.imap(predictor, X_test))
```

.

#### EDIT

Tested on a simplified example, the following solution takes 22 % of time less than the preceding one:

```
def predict(features,_classifier=None,_weights=None):
    probabilities = _classifier.predict_proba(features * _weights).ravel()
    label = np.argmax(probabilities)
    margin = 2 * probabilities[label] - np.sum(probabilities)
    return label, margin

def run_estimator(weights,
                  X_train=X_train,
                  y_train=y_train,
                  X_test=X_test,
                  y_test=y_test,
                  optimization=True,
                  predict = predict):

    classifier = get_classifier(weights, 
                                X_train=X_train,
                                y_train=y_train)

    predict.func_defaults = (classifier, weights)

    with Pool(processes=8) as pool:
        labels, margins = zip(*pool.imap(predict, X_test))
```

Comment: It works! Though I don't understand why. Thank you, kind wizard.

Comment: Update: this solution while being cleaner works ~20 times slower than mine. Could anybody provide explanation for that?

Comment: In my first answer, ``predictor`` is a new function created on the basis of ``predict``. If ``predictor = partial(predict,20,800)`` then ``predictor(x)`` will return the same result as ``predict(x,20,800)``. After I had written this first solution, I thought about the problem of time consuming because the instruction ``predictor = partial(predict,_classifier=..etc`` is executed at each call of ``run_estimator()`` and that means the creation of a new complex object at each call.

Comment: While in the edit, the only operation is reassigning a new tuple to the attribute ``func_defaults`` of the same functon ``predict``. The creation of a tuple being a simpler operation than the creation of a function object, I guessed that it would take less time to execute. A timing test with a similar simplified code confirmed my idea. I remain interested to know what influence it will have on time execution with your real code.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think this is the case, since I've ran the `run_estimator` only once. I'll try to isolate the problem and ask the question one more time.

Answer (score 1):

Wouldn't this work:

```
def predict(fcw):
    features, classifier, weights = fcw
    probabilities = classifier.predict_proba(features * weights).ravel()
    label = np.argmax(probabilities)
    margin = 2 * probabilities[label] - np.sum(probabilities)
    return label, margin

def run_estimator(weights, X_train=X_train, y_train=y_train, X_test=X_test, y_test=y_test, optimization=True):
    classifier = get_classifier(weights, X_train=X_train, y_train=y_train)

    classifier = classifier
    weights = weights

    wrapped_predict = lambda x: predict(x, classifier, weights)

    with Pool(processes=8) as pool:
        labels, margins = zip(*pool.imap(wrapped_predict, (X_test, classifier, weights)))
```

Comment: Nope, it still falls with `Can't pickle <class 'function'>`.

Comment: Ah - I misunderstood where the problem is. I believe the issue is that you're using multiprocess and it has to pickle anything used in an imap since that has to be sent to each subprocess. I believe you can fix that by creating a tuple and passing that as the argument to your function as tuples can be pickled/unpicked. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: This is not really different from your previous solution, and it still falls with the same error, since for a tuple to be picklable its contents must be picklable.